# how to kill process by loaded module in linux?

Tags: linux

is it possible to kill process by loaded modules?

for example,

```
[root@B6LEB1 network-scripts]# lsmod | grep ipv6
ipv6                  335525  61 ah6,esp6,xfrm6_mode_beet,xfrm6_mode_tunnel,ipcomp6,xfrm6_tunnel,tunnel6
```

when i tried to remove these module from runing,

```
[root@B6LEB1 network-scripts]# rmmod ipv6
ERROR: Module ipv6 is in use by ah6,esp6,xfrm6_mode_beet,xfrm6_mode_tunnel,ipcomp6,xfrm6_tunnel,tunnel6
```

it gave me error, so i wanted to try to kill the process which were using the above module, but ...

```
[root@B6LEB1 network-scripts]# ps aux | grep m6
root     13828  0.0  0.0 103308   860 pts/1    S+   08:42   0:00 grep m6
[root@B6LEB1 network-scripts]# ps aux | grep p6
root     18440  0.0  0.0 103308   860 pts/1    S+   08:42   0:00 grep p6
[root@B6LEB1 network-scripts]# pgrep ipv6
[root@B6LEB1 network-scripts]# ps aux | grep p6
```

any idea for this task? thanks

Comment: I do not recommend that you disable IPv6 access to your server these days, there are countries who do not have access to the IPv4 internet anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse "process" with "kernel module".

The list you quote isn't of processes that depend on the module (and, anyways, you can't kill a process launched by the kernel). It is a list of kernel modules.

Try to run `rmmod` on the names.

I'll just add that `rmmod` is not guaranteed to work either.